# How can I disable the wireless connection balloon when it connects?

Tags: windows-xp, wireless-networking

XP SP3

When my laptop connects to my wireless, a balloon appears, attached to the wireless icon in my tray. As sometimes my connection drops and re-connects, I may get this notification a few times. I find this very intrusive and would like to disable the balloon notification.

Any help?

Thanks.

Regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to Control Panel -> Network Connections -> Wireless Connection -> Properties.  At the bottom on the window uncheck "Show icon in notifcation area..." and "Notify me when this connection has limited or no connectivity".

Comment: This sounds correct. +1 and I will wait for a day to make sure it happens, and if so, I'll upvote. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307729) seems to disable all balloon tips; I'm not sure if you can disable it just for networking events.

> To disable balloon tips in the notification area, follow these steps:

```
1. Click Start, click Run, type regedit, and then press ENTER.
2. Locate the following subkey:
    HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion
    \Explorer\Advanced
3. Right-click the right side pane, create a new DWORD value, and then name it
   EnableBalloonTips.
4. Double-click EnableBalloonTips, and then give it a value of 0.
5. Close Registry Editor.
6. Log off Windows, and then log back on.
```